# vagrant provision: read line from keyboard/stdin

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

And so, I have a Vagrantfile with code:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
...
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'echo "Read line:" && read t && echo "$t"'
...
end
```

and when I execute `vagrant provision` i have that output:

```
$ vagrant provision
...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Read line:
==> default: exit
```

that is no suggest enter a line from keyboard/stdin!

What I should do for reading line from keyboard/stdin during provision shell script execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it this way, in my Vagrantfile

```
puts "Input text: "
input = STDIN.gets.chomp

config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo #{input}"
```

Comment: Yes, it is solution of my example `echo "Read line:" && read t && echo "$t"`.

But I need more general solution.
**How make it if in my provision shell script used command which requires keyboard input directly?**

Comment: as far as I last see, it was not possible ([reference](http://vagrant.1086180.n5.nabble.com/bootstrap-sh-pause-for-input-after-each-command-td1399.html)) and so I've been using this way - might have changed but I doubt, provisioning vagrant goal is really to be 100% automatic, in your case might not be perfect but you could workaround with the example I gave

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've read your reference. And I will use yours way.

Comment: Hi. I use yours way. It works! But now `vagrant destroy` required keyboard input:)

Comment: Oh right :) you can maybe had a check on the first argument of vagrant if "up" then add the key board input

Comment: This helped me but I wanted user input not to be displayed as they entered which is useful for a password prompt. `pass = STDIN.noecho(&:gets)`

Comment: this will ask every time you run vagrant up , cant use once option with it

Comment: @mrjamesmyers A line break is entered. Instead `pass = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp`